# Test file and testing file talking through each other

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I'm learning Ruby and RSpec, and I've hit a snag wherein most learning materials available have become deprecated and I lack the vocabulary to sift through the wreckage.

```
class Session

  def initialize(winning_score = 0)
    @winning_score = winning_score
    play
  end

  def play
    get_players
    max_score
    while #game is in play
      print_score
      #play game
    end
    winner
  end

  def get_players
    puts "\nPlayer X name:"
    p1 = gets.chomp.upcase
    @player1 = Player.new(p1, "X", 0)
    puts "\nPlayer O name:"
    p2 = gets.chomp.upcase
    @player2 = Player.new(p2, "O", 0)
  end

  def max_score
    puts "\nBest out of how many?"
    max = gets.chomp
    @winning_score = (max.to_f/2).ceil
  end

  def print_score
    puts "\n#{@player1.name}: #{@player1.score} \n#{@player2.name}: #{@player2.score}"
  end

  def winner
    if @player1.score == @winning_score
        puts "\n#{@player1.name} WINS!!!"
    elsif @player2.score == @winning_score
        puts "\n#{@player2.name} WINS!!!"
    end
  end
end

class Player

  attr_accessor :name, :mark, :score

  def initialize(name, mark, score)
    @name = name
    @mark = mark
    @score = score
  end

end
```

Rpec:

```
describe "Play" do

  before(:each) do 
    allow(x).to receive(:puts)
    allow(x).to receive(:print)
  end

  let(:x) { Session.new }

  it "displays game score" do
    @player1 = Player.new("p1", "X", 0)
    @player2 = Player.new("p2", "O", 2)
    expect(x).to receive(:puts).with("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
    x.print_score
    x.play
  end
end
```

... I think that's all the applicable bits of code... The problem is that the file being tested and the RSpec file keep talking through each other, and I keep getting this sort of thing:

```
1) play displays game score
 Failure/Error: expect(x).to receive(:puts).with("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
   #<Session:0x007fc16b9f5d38> received :puts with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
          got: ("\n\t\t: 0 \n\tEND: 0"), ("\nPlayer X name:"), ("\nPlayer O name:"), ("\nBest out of how many?"), ("\n\tIT \"GETS AND CREATES PLAYERS\" DO WINS!!!")
 # ./tictactoe_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

...where the noise is other methods gets.chomping the running RSpec code and storing it as the player names... I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening, clear/reset it, or what the correct course of action even is... Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement an optional output source at initialization that defaults to stdout, then create a double of that output source for the methods to puts to. After talking to a few more experienced devs, it seems to be a fairly common thing to do. Simplifying the code a bit would probably also be pretty thoroughly helpful... It's pretty bad looking back at it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are setting the `@player1` and `@player2` instance variables in the test context. While you need them inside your session object.

I think a good approach here would be to stub the get_players method, but we will have to change it a bit.

```
class Session

  #...

  def get_players
    @player1 = get_player("X")
    @player2 = get_player("O")
  end

  def get_player(mark)
    puts "\nPlayer #{mark} name:"
    name = gets.chomp.upcase
    Player.new(name, mark, 0)
  end

  #...

end
```

Now you can stub those get_player calls

```
  # ...

  it "displays game score" do
    allow(x).to recive(:get_player).with("X") { Player.new("p1", "X", 0) }
    allow(x).to recive(:get_player).with("O") { Player.new("p2", "O", 2) }

    expect(x).to receive(:puts).with("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
    x.print_score
    x.play
  end
```

Comment: I implemented these suggestions (there's two typos: "recive" should be "receive"), but it's still cross talking. 

Could you elaborate a bit on the stub concept and what exactly is going on there?

Also, why does it need x.print_score and x.play AFTER the rest of the test code? I've seen this, but don't understand it. There's very little I've been able to find on this subject.

Comment: 1) play displays game score
     Failure/Error: expect(x).to receive(:puts).with("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
       #<Session:0x007f919295c150> received :puts with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("\np1: 0 \np2: 2")
              got: ("\n: 0 \n\tIT \"GETS AND CREATES PLAYERS\" DO: 0"), ("\nBest out of how many?"), ("\np1 WINS!!!")
     # ./tictactoe_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'